# Unknown error when running lmer() mixed model

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I'm currently trying to run a repeated measures anova using the lme4 function. My data is as follows (top 6 values shown, n=40):

| Core | Substrate | Treatment | O2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M&S | C | -0.40 |
| 1 | S | C | -0.60 |
| 2 | M&S | C | -0.41 |
| 2 | S | C | -0.61 |
| 3 | M&S | D | -0.25 |
| 3 | S | D | -0.45 |

I would like to see if there is an effect of treatment on O2, and if this varies with Substrate. I have 2 measurements per core which occur at different time points so I would liked to control for repeated measures. To do this I used the below code:

```
mixed.lmer1 <- lmer(O2 ~ Treatment*Substrate+(1|Core), data = data)
summary(mixed.lmer1)
```

I then used the following code to test if there is a sig. effect of Core on the model:

```
mixed.lmer2 <- lm(O2 ~ Treatment*Substrate, data = data)
summary(mixed.lmer2)
anova(mixed.lmer2,mixed.lmer1)
```

However, when I ran the first model I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$pp), lower = rho$lower,  :
  convergence code -4 from nloptwrap
```

I was just wondering if anyone has come across this before? I can't seem to find anything online. I presume it is because I am overfitting the data as I only have 2 measurements per core. Is there anyway to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen that message before, either. The first thing I would do is try a different optimizer to see if results are similar while avoiding any warnings. :) You can do that by adding, e.g., `control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")` to your model. See `?lmerControl` for all the optimizers.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** this is a "stopped due to round-off" message, which *might* be happening because your response variable only has two digits of precision?

The [NLopt reference](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Reference/) says -4 denotes

> Halted because roundoff errors limited progress. (In this case, the optimization still typically returns a useful result.)

However, it's not really reasonable to expect you to dig that far (`lme4` → `nloptr` (R package/wrapper) → `NLopt` (C library)). You *might* be able to find equivalent information by printing `fitted_model@optinfo$message`.

Somewhere along the line from `nlopt` (a C/C++ optimization library) to `nloptr` (the R wrapper) to `lme4` (which further wraps `nloptr::nlopt()` to make it more compatible with other R optimization functions), the message got lost.

Digging around in the `nlopt` source code on GitHub also find [this list of status codes](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/blob/496be736b8b249273838b891f4c8ca3669551127/src/api/nlopt.h#L162-L175): negative values represent potential convergence problems.

```
typedef enum {
    NLOPT_FAILURE = -1,         /* generic failure code */
    NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS = -2,
    NLOPT_OUT_OF_MEMORY = -3,
    NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED = -4,
    NLOPT_FORCED_STOP = -5,
    NLOPT_SUCCESS = 1,          /* generic success code */
    NLOPT_STOPVAL_REACHED = 2,
    NLOPT_FTOL_REACHED = 3,
    NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED = 4,
    NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED = 5,
    NLOPT_MAXTIME_REACHED = 6,
    NLOPT_NUM_RESULTS           /* not a result, just the number of them */
} nlopt_result;
```